# jQuery Validation Plugin not showing custom messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Tried to create a registration form similar to the [documentation example](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) but can't get it to work. In Chrome Inspector it says "jquery.validate.js:640 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined" but I can't understand that code.

Actually the email field kind of works...[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Register</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quickipedia.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="js/register.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body class="q-site-background">

        <div id="q-banner"></div>       

            <div id="q-login">

                <form class="form-horizontal" id="registrationForm" role="form" action="register.php" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-span-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <h2 class="form-horizontal-heading">Register</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label for="username" class="control-label col-sm-4">Username: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus >
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label for="password" class="control-label col-sm-4">Password: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label for="confirm_password" class="control-label col-sm-4">Confirm Password: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-4">Email: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label for="confirm_email" class="control-label col-sm-4">Confirm Email: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="confirm_email" name="confirmEmail" placeholder="Confirm Email" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button id="#register" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block q-button col-span-4" type="submit">Create Account</button>

              </form>

              <br/>

        </div>  

    </body>

</html>
```

And register.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#registrationForm").validate({
        rules:{
            username:{
                required:true,
                minLength:4
            },
            password:{
                minLength:6,
                required:true
            }, 
            confirm_password:{
                minLength:6,
                required:true,
                equalTo:"#password"
            }, 
            email:{
                required:true,
                email:true
            },
            confirm_email:{
                required:true,
                email:true,
                equalTo:"#email"
            }
        },
        messages:{
            username:{
                required:"Please enter a username",
                minLength:"Username must be at least 4 characters long"
            },
            password:{
                required:"Please enter a password",
                minLength:"Password must be at least 6 characters"
            },
            confirm_password:{
                required:"Please confirm password",
                minLength:"Password must be at least 6 characters",
                equalTo:"Passwords do not match"
            },
            email:"Please enter an email",
            confirm_email:{ 
                required:"Please confirm email",
                equalTo:"Emails do not match"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I've checked over the syntax a billion times and can't find any errors. Also, it works if I include the HTML input attributes (e.g. required minLength="6" equalTo="#password") but that just shows the standard messages. I want to use the customized ones I've created but nothing shows up.

Comment: Please never fix your code within the question... it renders the answers useless.  Feel free to append new information however.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've checked over the syntax a billion times and can't find any errors.

There is no such rule called `minLength`.  That's the source of your "undefined" error.

[It's `minlength`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method/). *(note the exact spelling)*

```
$("#registrationForm").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        },
        ....
```

---

You are also going to have a problem here...

```
confirm_email: {  // <- THIS IS SUPPOSED TO BE THE NAME ATTRIBUTE
    required:true,
    email:true,
    equalTo:"#email"
}
```

Rules within the `rules` option are defined by the field's `name` attribute, **not** by their `id`.

Comment: ah ok I figured it would be some stupid oversight like that on my part. You sir are a lifesaver!